# Assembly returning false

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly

In IDA I see:

```
mov     ecx, [esp+130h+dwProcessId]
push    eax
push    ecx
call    sub_FE13A0
add     esp, 8
test    al, al
jnz     short loc_FE1261
```

which is currently returning false which causes the program to terminate. Can someone explain what exactly the conditional in the last two lines are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bet the last two instructions compare the return value from `sub_FE13A0(...)` with 0 and jmp to `loc_FE1261` if it's not 0 otherwise continue execution past `jnz`.

Comment: Your right, I was thinking of it totally wrong. I assumed that the issue was this function, the program is actually terminating in sub_FE13A0, but I assumed it would be in loc_FE1261 which is actually just where the winmain function returns 0.